# How to pass data from Java to a JavaScript web application?

Tags: javascript, java

I have two applications: (1) a JavaFX application A and (2) a purely JavaScript web application B (no backend) accessed either as local files (for developers) or at a certain URL (for the users).

In A the user can save a file and then open B in the user's browser via `Desktop.getDesktop().browse()`. Then the user can load that file in B by clicking on an `input` element of type `file`, which allows the usage of `FileReader`.

That process is too cumbersome for the users, so I want to remove that requirement of the user to save and load a file.

My problem is: How can I transfer this data from A to B now?

- GET parameters only allow a few thousand characters, which is not enough for us
- I see no way to pass POST parameters from Java to the browser and also to access those parameters from within JavaScript
- `FileReader` cannot read files using path names because of security
- we can't use platform or browser dependent native code solutions because the users use different OSes and browsers
- the web application uses many libraries and advanced JavaScript features, which I don't expect a JavaFX HTML window to support

Is there any way to get one of the above methods to work or is there any alternative to pass data between Java and a purely client-based JavaScript application in a browser?

### Update

As suggested in the accepted answer, I serve the data as using Jetty.

#### 1. Java: Define JSON Server

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class JsonServer extends Server
{
    static final int PORT = 1234;  

    public JsonServer(JSONArray json)
    {
        super(PORT);
        setHandler(new JsonHandler(json));
    }

    public static class JsonHandler extends AbstractHandler
    {
        final JSONArray json;

        public JsonHandler(JSONArray json)
        {
            this.json = json;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
        {
            response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

            try(PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();)
            {
                out.println(json);
            }
            baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        }

    }
}
```

#### 2. Java: Start Server

```
            Server server = new JsonServer(json);
            server.start();
            browse("https://myapp.com?load=http://localhost:1234");
```

#### 3. JavaScript: Fetch

```
    const load = url.searchParams.get("load");
    const json = await (await fetch(load)).json();
```

Comment: Without a backend to application B, you have no other options as far as I can see. Have you actually tried the JavaFX HTML window though? If it relies on a standard browser rendering engine behind it then you might find it's ok

Comment: Another thought: What does application B actually do with the files the user loads into it? Could you not just implement the same feature in the Java application? I'm not seeing what the advantage of a separate web application is if it doesn't have a server backend of any kind

Comment: @ADyson: Application B was developed over many months, it would be too much effort to re-implement it in Java just for A, which is a much smaller tool.

Comment: You could dynamically generate an HTML file in your Java app that would contain the Web app (javascript) and the data it needs, and invoke that file from the Java app.

Comment: @georg: That would be useful if A was big and B very small but it is the other way around. B is updated often and uses npm, babel and so on. It would be too much hassle to include it on the users PC and update and build it.

Comment: @KonradHöffner: so the Web App does use a webserver? It's not a local file? Then, you can make the Java App post the data to that server, so that the webapp can take it from there.

Comment: @georg: The Web App does not always use a webserver. For developers, it is just opened in the browser over the file protocol. Also, I cannot access POST data from within JavaScript.

Comment: Why do developers access it a different way? That makes no sense, and loading over the file protocol is never recommended anyway. What stops the developers just using it the normal way? And no your JavaScript cannot read the post data direct, but if a server endpoint received that data and stores it, then the JavaScript can load it from the server when required.

Comment: @ADyson: I would rather discuss the how than the why to not get too distracted from the scope of the problem, but the reason for the file protocol is that the developers just run the code as is without postprocessing. The users instead get a compiled version that is minified, sent through babel to be compatible with older browsers and so on. Of course we could just have all developers use a local web server but we want to keep everything as simple as possible.

Comment: My point I suppose was that the use of the file protocol would make it more difficult to download the received data from the server (as per my suggestion to deal with the posted file data) since in the file scenario there is no server, and you might run into things like CORS issues. P.s. there's no reason developers can't run a non-minified version on a development server for the purpose of debugging. I can't really see why they'd need that in the live environment particularly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that the web page is always going to be viewed on the same machine that is running the JavaFX application you could always have it export the file via HTTP (using [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/about.html) or similar), then have the web page load the data using a URL such as "http://localhost:port/fileContainingData".

Comment: The webpage will indeed be viewed on the same machine, this is a great suggestion, I will try it out!